# Есть ли смысл регулярно менять крупный (30 символов?) ключ доступа к секретному файлу?

Tags: php, шифрование

Рассматриваю два варианта шифрования ссылки.

1. Есть секретное слово, которое меняется каждый раз дня каждого пользователя и состоит из ~ 30 символов.
2. Секретное слово всегда одно и то же.

Вопрос в том что - естественно найдется умный человек, который раскодирует ссылку, но больше времени понадобится ли при первом варианте или же нет?

Ну и может кто то подскажет хорошую библиотеку на php, чтобы закодировать ссылку на файл?

Comment: а зачем вы хотите кодировать ссылку? Идея ваша в чем?

Comment: Да это не мне нужно, а доказать человеку, что спрятать файл кодированной ссылкой нельзя, но он хочет... =)

Comment: Создание своих велосипедов в криптографии чревато костылями.

Comment: А зачем прятать файл кодированной ссылкой, когда можно просто взять буквоцифры случайным образом, как это делают все файлообменники?)

Comment: @andreymal просто md5( + currenttimestamp)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев а зачем md5, когда можно просто взять буквоцифры случайным образом?))

Comment: Вот и я о том, но ему хочется, чтобы ссылки выглядели так

Comment: wNp5zu3KlR4hQtMsSxOdzxyTVQDAAIf6WMmeJha3Zc8

Comment: Вполне похоже на случайные буквоцифры

Comment: Короче все что я хотел узнать - узнал. ) 
Спасибо. =)

Comment: @andreymal потому что, возможны повторы) a md5( + время) не повторится

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев даже всего на шести символах, даже если заливать по одному файлу в секунду повторы становятся хоть немного возможными только через десяток-другой лет) А если же брать 43 символа (как в примере выше), то стопудово не появится ни одного повтора аж до тепловой смерти Вселенной :D

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев а время, кстати, повториться теоретически может. Недостаточная точность (зависит от конкретного случая), изменение часовых поясов, переезд сервера в страны чуток западнее, летнее/зимнее время, просто корректировка времени если часы вдруг спешат, вот это вот всё

Comment: @andreymal время не повторяется, а при переезде, на N количество поясов, вероятность совпадения приближаются к 0. Так что это нереально.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев вероятность совпадения 46 случайных символов *намнооооооооого* ближе к нулю, чем вероятность совпадения времени :)

Comment: а теперь смотри длину моей строки и твоей из 46 символов. Моя короче, в принципе имеет такую же вероятность как у тебя. Но ты можешь ещё прибавить ко всему этому и рандомное число, и тогда повтор уже будет недостижим, а длина останется прежней

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40702/discussion-between-andreymal-and--). Сейчас я там буду теорию вероятности преподавать :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Секретное слово **расшифровать** нельзя, не из чего. Его можно разве что **угадать** (или *украсть*, но это читерство, не рассматриваем).

**Скорее всего** ваша система недостаточно мощная (или в слове достаточно энтропии), чтобы дать злоумышленнику опробовать все возможные комбинации за один день, поэтому считаем, что хотя бы одна смена всё-таки произошла.

Новая ситуация возникает всего одна. Если смена произошла на комбинацию, которую атакующий уже опробовал, то в результате успешного **перебора без повторов** он может не найти правильный ответ.

Поэтому смена слова каждый день может улучшить ситуацию, но чисто теоретически. Даже без неё подобная атака трудноосуществима на практике, потому что чтобы уложиться в разумное время, перебор вынужден будет производиться с **огромной** скоростью, давая **огромную** нагрузку на систему, вызывая **огромные** задержки и потенциально отказ всего сайта, что... вы же заметите, наверное?